# jquery use image alt text as link anchor text

Tags: jquery, alt

i'm trying to use an image's alt text and use it as the text for its corresponding anchor tag.

this would be used at some point in a slide show.

this is what i have so far, but it's inserting the all text for anything other than the first image in the div. what am i missing?

[Here's the jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/ibeha4/130/edit#javascript,html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("div img[alt^='slide']").each(function(i, item){
    var imageAlt = $(item).attr("alt");
    var text = "this is " + imageAlt + ".";
    console.log(imageAlt);
    $("ul a").eq(i).text(text);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/g33H8/1/

Comment: that didn't do anything. my html already had 1-5 hard coded, but it should have said slide1 alt text, slide2 alt text, etc ...

Comment: thanks neal! i felt like i was on the right track. now i can go back and look at .each a little closer.

Comment: @thursday0384 no problem ^_^ remember to select an accepted answer to your questions when you can ^_^

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to chat so i'm going to ask for clarification. i was reading about .each tonight and im unclear about one thing. i understand the role of the index parameter, but i'm unsure about how the element parameter works. could you explain